Can I apply taylor expansion to exponents?
If I have a limit in this form:
$$\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)^{g(x)}$$
can I expand $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ to end up with a limit like:
$$\lim_{x\to x_0}\left(f(0) + f'(0)x + \frac{f''(0)}2x^2 + \cdots\right)^{g(0) + g'(0)x + \frac{g''(0)}2x^2 + \cdots}$$
then cut up the series and write:
$$\lim_{x\to x_0}\left(f(0) + f'(0)x + \frac{f''(0)}2x^2\right)^{g(0) + g'(0)x + \frac{g''(0)}2x^2}$$
and work on this one instead? Or is this not allowed for some obscure reason? $x_0$ is within the radius of convergence of both expansions.
EDIT: I'll add an example which I've seen today on this website:
$$\lim_{\theta\to0^+}(\sin\theta)^{\sin\theta-\sin^2\theta}$$
Can I use the fact that $\sin\theta\sim\theta$ and say that this limit is equivalent to the following?
$$\lim_{\theta\to0^+}\theta^{\theta(1-\theta)}$$
The result is the same, but it could be a coincidence. Is this procedure correct here? In the general case?
Thanks in advance.

If you expand about $0$, you'll need to assume $f(0)>0$ because of cases such as $x^x$.

@J.G. what if I expand about $1$?

I would recommend taking the log at the beginning and using your Taylor expansion (about $x_0$) to examine $g(x)\log f(x)$. (Or write $\ln$ for $\log$, depending on where you live.)

@TedShifrin But if $f(0)=x_0=0$ I can't do that.

Why don't you edit your question to include a precise example? Note that the standard way of computing $\lim_{x\to 0^+} x^x$ is to take the logarithm.

@TedShifrin's comment is excellent for more than one reason, but I'll highlight one that mustn't be overlooked: the limit has to be one-sided to exist, which is not what you want if you try the kind of expansion this question seeks.

Note that $$\log(x+o(x)) = \log x + \log(1+o(x)/x).$$ Now multiply by $g(x)$ (or its Taylor expansion) and work this out.

@TedShifrin done, I've included an example.

As I suggested in the comments, write
$$\sin x = x + \epsilon_1(x), \quad\text{where } \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\epsilon_1(x)}x = 0.$$
Then $\sin^2 x=x^2+\epsilon_1(x)$, with $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\dfrac{\epsilon_2(x)}{x^2}=0$.
For $x>0$, we have
\begin{align*}
\log\left(\sin x)^{\sin x-\sin^2x}\right) &= (\sin x-\sin^2x)\log(\sin x) \\
&= (x-x^2+\epsilon(x))\log(x+\epsilon_1(x)) \quad\text{with }\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\epsilon(x)}x = 0 \\&= (x-x^2+\epsilon(x))\log x+(x-x^2+\epsilon(x)\log\left(1+\frac{\epsilon_1(x)}x\right) \\ 
&=x\left(1-x+\frac{\epsilon(x)}x\right)\log x +(x-x^2+\epsilon(x))\log\left(1+\frac{\epsilon_1(x)}x\right).
\end{align*}
Now finish by using $\lim\limits_{x\to 0^+} x\log x = 0$ and the usual limit laws.
